# Problem with Array.shift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

From my controller I am passing two instance variables `@events = Event.all` and `@images = Images.all`. In the view I begin by iterating through `@events.each do |event|` and within this block is the line `img = @images.shift` yet when I try to access any method of `img` such as `img.filename` I get an error that `img` is  `nil` but I have checked and am certain that `@images` is populated correctly. If I simply output `img.class` I receive the correct class, `Image`, but cannot access any of it's methods.

What am I doing wrong or why is this way of pulling instances from an array incorrect?

I know there are other ways of going about this but this specific problem confounds me and I would really like to understand why this doesn't work. Thanks.

```
#Structure of the model is
Image
-filename :string
-date     :datetime
-caption  :text
-source   :string

#Controller
def index
  @events = Event.all
  @images = Image.all
end

#index.html.erb
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  ... code that works ...

  <% if count==1%>
    <% img = @images.shift %>
    <div><%= img.filename %></div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>

#For testing purposes I changed
<% img = @images.shift %>
<div><%= img.class %></div>

#output is Image
```

Comment: Can you reformat that to include a small example piece of code instead of a bunch of code segments threaded in a paragraph? It will readability IMO

Comment: maybe it returns `nil` when all your images have been shifted already?

Comment: I support @nash's comment, that could definitely be the case

Comment: Is this correct: @images = Images.all? Whats the name of your Image model? #shift can return nil when the array is empty.

Comment: Thank you! Nash you were right, I overlooked that.

Comment: I placed the `@images.shift` within an `unless @images.empty?` block and it works flawlessly. Man I feel stupid. Thank you again for the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might occur when there is more events then images. Because every time an iteration goes through @events array then the @images are shifted and is taken the next element from the array. So when you have for example 4 elements in @events and only 3 in @images then at 4th iteration there is taken 4th element from @images and this is `nil`

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases when the return value of `Array#shift` becomes `nil`.

1. The leftmost element of the array is `nil`.
2. The array is empty (= `[]`).

It is probably either of the cases.

Comment: `@images` is an array of `Image` instances. `Image` is not a subclass of `Array`.